# Building a chrome extension- can't get it to block a div

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Im building a chrome extention. Im trying to block the arrows on redditp with the click on a button that only comes up when youa re on the site. The site in question is www.redditp.com.

Manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Redditp Button Disabler",
"version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Disable ugly buttons on Redditp. Made by Algy.",
  "permissions": ["https://redditp.com/"],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
        "http://redditp.com/*"],
        "js": ["main.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Main.js

```
document.querySelector('div#nextButton').innerHTML = '';
```

What have I done to mess it up? At the moment i'm just trying to get it to remove the right arrow, because I assume once I know how to do one, ill be able to remove everything else I need to. When I want it to remove more, can I just put it under the first line of code? Also do I need to do anything to get my icon to show up and execute the code upon click?

Thanks Guys.

Comment: "What have I done to mess it up?" - Would be impossible to say since I don't know in what way it's not working as desired. "can I just put it under the first line of code?" - Each line of code will be executed one after the other, so yes. "Also do I need to do anything to get my icon to show up and execute the code upon click?" - ?? Were you just hoping this would happen by magic? If you want to cause something to happen wouldn't it make sense you probably do need to do something?

Comment: Well when I activated the extension it did nothing, which is why I'm here, I probably should have made that clearer.